# Altium Designer multi channel flat annotation

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, pcb-design, altium

I'm trying to anotate a multichannel design in Altium Designer.
It works fine - here is what I have done:

- Top schematic:
  [image: top Schematic]
- Project tree:
  [image: Project]
- Multi-channel room naming setting:
  [image: Multi-channel room naming]
- PCB anotation:
  [image: PCB anotation]

Now I want to anotate the schematic in Flat style rather than $Component_$RoomName style.
I found no way of doing this other than anotating the PCB first and then updating schematic from PCB.

PCB Anotation:
[image]

Update schematic From PCB:
[image]

I have no idea how to add/remove some components to the schematic and anotate them in flat style.
Is there any straight forward way to do this other than the above way?

Answer (score 0):

i Found the Solution using this video tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVbrohnLOac

Comment: Please add this to the top of your question as an update, with a little detail about what was involved.